# TS1128: Declaration or statement expected (end of file)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am working on a TypeScript/React project (just getting used to it, haven't written React in a year, etc.), and having an issue.

When I wrote this component, I followed some docs that I found, but I'm getting a TS1128 (Declaration or statement expected) error at the end of this file, and I can't figure out why:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Count from './CountDisplay';

interface State {
    count: number;
}

class Counter extends React.Component<{}, State> {

    state: State = {count: 0};

    increment() {
        this.setState({
            count: (this.state.count + 1)
        });
    }

    decrement() {
        this.setState({
            count: (this.state.count - 1)
        });
    }

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <div>
                <Count count={this.state.count}/>
                <button onClick={this.increment}>Increment</button>
                <button onClick={this.decrement}>Decrement</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

I don't know, why I keep getting an error, because the code looks fine (or so I thought), but I could be wrong.

Below is my TSConfig.json, because I figured maybe it's relevant to the issue:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react"
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect its your `render` function.  If  you comment it out, does the error go away?

Comment: Nope, I actually tried commenting out each of the functions one at a time, and it still persists.

Answer (score 66):

### Update 11/05/2020:

Closing and reopening the file fixes it as well. It seems IntelliJ TypeScript parsing can get out of sync.

### Original answer

I might be a little late to the party, but I also experienced this and what fixed it for me were the following steps.

1. Create a new file.
2. Copy the contents of the old file to the new file.
3. Delete the old file.
4. Rename the new file to match the old file's name.

Now I'm not exactly sure *why* that fixes the issue, but I have a few guesses.
I'm using IntelliJ, which is I assume what you're using too since I've never had this issue elsewhere, and TS compiles just fine even with the issue present. It's more of an in-editor-error kind of deal (for me at least). Reopening the editor may fix this as well.

Hope this all helps!

#### <del>Guess 1</del>

<del>Something to do with line endings. Git changes your line endings when you do common git operations based on your OS, since Windows & Linux have different line-ending sequences. That may be something tripping IntelliJ up. I once hit this issue after pulling from `master` on a project, so that gives me this impression.</del>

#### <del>Guess 2</del>

<del>You have an "invisible" inserted unicode character somewhere in your code. This happened to me a few times, due to a custom MacOS keyboard layout.

Both of my hunches hover around things to do with "invisible" characters, but I'm afraid this is where my expertise ends. Maybe someone with some more know-how can chime in down the line.</del>

Comment: I had the same issue, found this answer, and was going to try it, but accidentally renamed folder with the file instead. Then I Cmd+Z it, and the issue disappeared. So I assume, renaming the file itself and Cmd+Z it would work as well.

Answer (score 5):

When I had this problem in WebStorm 2019.3.1 I was able to resolve it by going to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... and pressing the "Invalidate and Restart" button.  When WebStorm restarted the error was gone.

Answer (score 4):

Turn off Typescript Language Service in Settings > Language & Frameworks > Typescript . Then turn it back on. This solved it for me.

Comment: Simple, stupid but worked for me! Thanks :)

Comment: @RobAudenaerde many times the answer is simple

Answer (score 3):

Unchecking *Recompile on changes* in **Settings > Language & Frameworks > Typescript > Typescript Language Service** solved the issue, albeit the underlying cause remains unknown.

Comment: That _may_ not be a great idea?
A good workflow I have found is, I like to get compilation errors as soon as possible. A moment of "Oh, I messed something obvious up, let me fix that before continuing my train of thought". Either that, or I'm doing refactoring, and I've made substantial base change, and am relying on the compiler errors to guide me to update all the relevant code.
I (personally) don't seem to get this bug enough to warrant turning off compilation on save.

Answer (score 3):

This helped me in Webstorm IDE:

[image]

Comment: Is there a better fix? I still have to do this in the current version.